# Changing memory address values and hex data

Tags: c++, memory, memory-address, cheat-engine

So i want to change the value of an address to something else.
Say if the value of the address is **42859105827** and the address is **0A2BC6FC**, How would i change the value of this address?

Example:

```
Address    |    Type    |   Value
0A2BC6FC      4 Bytes      42859105827
```

Comment: `42859105827` is larger than 4 bytes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assign a value to a specific address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400018/assign-a-value-to-a-specific-address)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll need to reinterpret cast. This probably isn't a super safe way but should work:

```
size_t address = 0x0A2BC6FC;
int new_value = ...;
reinterpret_cast<int&>(address) = new_value;
```